# kotlin regex find "at start of input"

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, compiler-construction, tokenize

When using `regex.find(input,pos)`, can I make kotlin treat `pos` as the start of the line?

i.e:

```
val s = "foo(2)"

/*let's say I already extracted "foo"
  and now want to extract tokens '(', '2' and ')'
*/

val r1a = "\\(".toRegex()
val r1b = "\\)".toRegex()

println(r1a.find(s,3)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println(r1b.find(s,3)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println()

//this finds both
//but I only want to find '(' because it's at the beginning of the remaining string

val r2a = "^\\(".toRegex()
val r2b = "^\\)".toRegex()

println(r2a.find(s,3)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println(r2b.find(s,3)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println()

//this finds neither.
//I want the following behaviour:

val ss = s.substring(3)
println(r2a.find(ss,0)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println(r2b.find(ss,0)?.let{"found '${it.value}'"} ?: "Nothing found")
println()

/*which finds '(' but not ')',
  but without having to explicitly split the string
*/
```

([ideone version](https://ideone.com/qJn9cM/))

Is there a way to make this happen?

**EDIT**

I do *NOT* want to match "foo(2)".

I want to be able to feed this String into a list of matchers that will match first `foo` then `(` then `2` then `)`.

```
fun tokenizeLine(line:String){
    var pos = 0
    while(pos < line.length){
        val result = nextToken(line,pos)
        pos += result.consumed
        result.token?.let { tokens.add(it) }
    }
    tokens.add(Token.EOL)
}
```

where each matcher returns one of

```
sealed class TokenizerResult(val consumed : Int, val token:Token?){
    class Something(consumed:Int, token:Token):TokenizerResult(consumed,token)
    class Skip(consumed:Int=0):TokenizerResult(consumed,null)
    object Nothing:TokenizerResult(0,null)
}
```

and `fun nextToken(input:String, pos:Int) : TokenizerResult` walks through a list of matchers until it either runs out of matchers to try *or* one of the matchers returns something that is not `TokenizerResult.Nothing`.

```
val matchers = listOf( skipWhitespace, number, parensOpen, parensClose, identifier, ... )

for(m in matchers){
    result = m(input,pos)
    if(result != TNothing) break
}

if(result == TNothing){
    ...
}

return result
```

EDIT 2

The matchers generally work like this:

```
class RawMatch(val regex:Regex) : Pattern{
    override fun match(input: String, pos: Int, createToken: (value: String) -> Token): TokenizerResult {
        return regex.find(input,pos)?.let { TSomething(it.value.length,createToken(it.value)) } ?: TNothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to find `(` or `)` that is right after `foo`. Try `"""(?<=foo)[()]"""`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I do not. I want a way to write a pattern that will match the beginning of the input being considered -- which in this example *happens* to be at the ``(`` after ``foo``.

Comment: How do you know when a string should be split apart?  Is it a format like "<text><parenthesis><value><parenthesis>"?  Or is it something else?

Comment: You could always remove the substrings matched at each step from the string. But that seems like an hassle, I don't see why you wouldn't use multipe capturing groups in a single regex rather than multiple regexs

Comment: @MFazio23 the string isn't split apart. rather, however many characters match a certain pattern are taken to form a token (see edit)

Comment: @Aaron wouldn't "multiple capturing groups in a single regex" require per-command regexes, instead, resulting again in multiple regexes? And this "fetch-from-the-front" approach would work nicely to tokenize expressions.

Comment: You could build a regex around the `\G` operator, see https://regex101.com/r/YCdLen/1/

Comment: Yeah, nevermind my previous suggestion, I hadn't properly read your question. If you don't ever need to go back when parsing then dropping the parsed parts should work for you, otherwise Wiktor's suggestion of using `\G` seems promising if you're able to reuse the same matcher.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to find the value of whatever is in the parentheses, you can use a different regex along with `find` and `groupValues`:

```
val str = "foo(2)"
val regex = "\\s*\\((\\d*)\\)".toRegex()

println(regex.find(str)?.groupValues?.last())
```

The regex looks for any string value at the front, then a number inside of parentheses.  The number itself is grouped by a set of parentheses to be pulled out via the `groupValues` variable.  Without the string escapes, the regex is like this:

```
\s*\((\d*)\)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, this is not what I'm looking for (see edit).